# WMS and WFS time search criterion (dimension)

Tags: geoserver, wms

WMS accepts a time criterion ([1]). Does WFS also accept a time criterion (I don't see anything in [2])? There is some discussion on [3] but it is not clear. I am especially interested in GeoServer supports it (if possible).

[1] http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html#wms-time

[2] http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html

[3] https://web.archive.org/web/20180318045748/http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/178

Answer (score 3):

WFS doesn't support dimensions as a separate concept, it does provide a [well-documented](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/filter_reference.html) [filter capability](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter) that serves the same end.

Comment: Clear. Thank you @Ian.